# Statefulset Kubernetes : volumeMounts[0].name: Not found

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, kubernetes-statefulset, statefulset, nfs-subdir-external-provisioner

In https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/cassandra/ we read in the `/application/cassandra/cassandra-statefulset.yaml` sample:

[image]

So... I deployed an `nfs-subdir-external-provisioner` following these indications: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/blob/master/charts/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/README.md#install-multiple-provisioners , specifying the `volume name used inside the pod` through `nfs.volumeName` :

[image]

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# helm install k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner nfs-subdir-external-provisioner/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner \
> --set nfs.server=38.242.249.121 \
> --set nfs.path=/srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1 \
> --set storageClass.name=k8s-eu-1-worker-1 \
> --set storageClass.provisionerName=k8s-sigs.io/k8s-eu-1-worker-1 \
> --set nfs.volumeName=k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-v
NAME: k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Nov  7 17:14:42 2023
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# helm ls
NAME                                                NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART                                   APP VERSION
k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner   default     1           2023-11-07 17:14:42.197847444 +0100 CET deployed    nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-4.0.18  4.0.2      

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get deployments
NAME                                                READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner   1/1     1            1           2m9s

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get pods
NAME                                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-79fff4ff2qx7k   1/1     Running   0          2m27s
```

output of `kubuectl describe pod` :

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe pod k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-79fff4ff2qx7k
Name:             k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-79fff4ff2qx7k
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
Node:             k8s-eu-1-worker-2/yy.yyy.yyy.yyy
Start Time:       Tue, 07 Nov 2023 17:14:42 +0100
Labels:           app=nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
                  pod-template-hash=79fff4ff6
                  release=k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 2c7d048ecf0861c60a471e93e41d20dca0c7c58c20a3369ed1463820e898d1a7
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.236.18/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.236.18/32
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.236.18
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.236.18
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-79fff4ff6
Containers:
  nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:
    Container ID:   containerd://c4afd4f56bdb2d69aa2be23d6d47e843ceaa1f823459c7cffbf5dc859f59e44b
    Image:          registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2
    Image ID:       registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner@sha256:63d5e04551ec8b5aae83b6f35938ca5ddc50a88d85492d9731810c31591fa4c9
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Tue, 07 Nov 2023 17:14:43 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      PROVISIONER_NAME:  k8s-sigs.io/k8s-eu-1-worker-1
      NFS_SERVER:        xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
      NFS_PATH:          /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1
    Mounts:
      /persistentvolumes from k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-v (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-knxw8 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-v:  // <---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Type:      NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
    Server:   xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Path:      /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1
    ReadOnly:  false
  kube-api-access-knxw8:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  2m49s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-subdir-external-provisioner-79fff4ff2qx7k to k8s-eu-1-worker-2
  Normal  Pulled     2m49s  kubelet            Container image "registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner:v4.0.2" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    2m49s  kubelet            Created container nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
  Normal  Started    2m49s  kubelet            Started container nfs-subdir-external-provisioner
```

In `cassandra-statefulset.yaml` I've set the `volumeMounts as` pod's volume` : "k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-v" :

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-v
      mountPath: /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1
```

This is the entire `cassandra-statefulset.yaml` :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cassandra
  labels:
    app: cassandra
spec:
  serviceName: cassandra
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cassandra
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cassandra
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 1800
      containers:
      - name: cassandra
        image: gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7000
          name: intra-node
        - containerPort: 7001
          name: tls-intra-node
        - containerPort: 7199
          name: jmx
        - containerPort: 9042
          name: cql
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 1Gi
          requests:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: 1Gi
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - IPC_LOCK
        lifecycle:
          preStop:
            exec:
              command: 
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - nodetool drain
        env:
          - name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE
            value: 512M
          - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE
            value: 100M
          - name: CASSANDRA_SEEDS
            value: "cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local"
          - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
            value: "K8Demo"
          - name: CASSANDRA_DC
            value: "DC1-K8Demo"
          - name: CASSANDRA_RACK
            value: "Rack1-K8Demo"
          - name: POD_IP
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
            - /ready-probe.sh
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 5
        # These volume mounts are persistent. They are like inline claims,
        # but not exactly because the names need to match exactly one of
        # the stateful pod volumes.
        volumeMounts:
        - name: k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-v
          mountPath: /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1

  # These are converted to volume claims by the controller
  # and mounted at the paths mentioned above.
  # do not use these in production until ssd GCEPersistentDisk or other ssd pd
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: k8s-eu-1-worker-1
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: k8s-eu-1-worker-1
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: k8s-eu-1-worker-1
provisioner: k8s-sigs.io/k8s-eu-1-worker-1
parameters:
  #type: pd-ss
```

When I apply this configuration I get : `spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-`

```
root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl apply -f ./cassandraStatefulApp/cassandra-statefulset.yaml 
statefulset.apps/cassandra created
Warning: resource storageclasses/k8s-eu-1-worker-1 is missing the kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration annotation which is required by kubectl apply. kubectl apply should only be used on resources created declaratively by either kubectl create --save-config or kubectl apply. The missing annotation will be patched automatically.
The StorageClass "k8s-eu-1-worker-1" is invalid: parameters: Forbidden: updates to parameters are forbidden.

root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl get statefulsets
NAME        READY   AGE
cassandra   0/3     21s


root@k8s-eu-1-master:~# kubectl describe statefulsets cassandra
Name:               cassandra
Namespace:          default
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 07 Nov 2023 17:33:40 +0100
Selector:           app=cassandra
Labels:             app=cassandra
Annotations:        <none>
Replicas:           3 desired | 0 total
Update Strategy:    RollingUpdate
  Partition:        0
Pods Status:        0 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=cassandra
  Containers:
   cassandra:
    Image:       gcr.io/google-samples/cassandra:v13
    Ports:       7000/TCP, 7001/TCP, 7199/TCP, 9042/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:      500m
      memory:   1Gi
    Readiness:  exec [/bin/bash -c /ready-probe.sh] delay=15s timeout=5s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MAX_HEAP_SIZE:           512M
      HEAP_NEWSIZE:            100M
      CASSANDRA_SEEDS:         cassandra-0.cassandra.default.svc.cluster.local
      CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME:  K8Demo
      CASSANDRA_DC:            DC1-K8Demo
      CASSANDRA_RACK:          Rack1-K8Demo
      POD_IP:                   (v1:status.podIP)
    Mounts:
      /srv/shared-k8s-eu-1-worker-1 from k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-v (rw)
  Volumes:  <none>
Volume Claims:
  Name:          k8s-eu-1-worker-1
  StorageClass:  k8s-eu-1-worker-1
  Labels:        <none>
  Annotations:   <none>
  Capacity:      1Gi
  Access Modes:  [ReadWriteOnce]
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                 From                    Message
  ----     ------        ----                ----                    -------
  Warning  FailedCreate  20s (x13 over 41s)  statefulset-controller  create Pod cassandra-0 in StatefulSet cassandra failed error: Pod "cassandra-0" is invalid: spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "k8s-eu-1-worker-1-nfs-v"
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to specify within the `statefulset.yaml` file the `name` of the `VolumeMounts` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a kind kubernetes expert I managed to understand that two metadata names has to match :

```
volumeClaimTemplates:

metadata: name: k8s-eu-1-worker-1 // <-------------

kind: StorageClass apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata: name: k8s-eu-1-worker-1 // <------------- provisioner: k8s-sigs.io/k8s-eu-1-worker-1 parameters: type: pd-ssd
```